# How to change font size for iPhone 4 and IPhone 5 in auto-layout?

Tags: ios8, uilabel, uifont, ios-autolayout

I am trying to change font size of uilabel for iphone 4 and iphone 5 using autolayout and size classes. IB is giving option only for ipad and greater phones like iphone 6 and 6P .

If i change font for wR and hR then it changes fonts size for iphone 4 , 5 and 6 which is wrong in my case .

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately , Apple Provides minimum consideration for all iPhone's(4,5,6,6p version) Portrait Mode    `Compact Width - Compact Height` or `Compact Width - Regular Height`. So You can't  specify Font Size separately for different iPhones in Portrait Mode from Storyboard.